# Replacing '\/'' with sed

Tags: linux, sed

How can I replace below string `\/` by `|` like:

```
bssapi_6 0\/0\/0\/9\/9

bssapi_6 0|0|0|9|9
```

Comment: Like this?
`echo bssapi_6 0\/0\/0\/9\/9 | sed 's/\//|/g;'`

EDIT: I used echo since most of the answers used other ways

Answer (score 6):

With liberal amounts of escaping applied:

```
sed 's/\\\//|/g' < inputfile
```

Making it more readable by using `@` as a separator:

```
sed 's@\\/@|@g' < inputfile
```

Comment: hehe I guess it now depends whether the OP prefers `_` or `@`

Comment: The same answer as so often: The separator used by sed's `s` command is determined by the character immediately following it. One can use any character here.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
sed 's/\\\//|/g' your_file
```

or, using `_` as a pattern delimiter so we don't need to escape the `/`:

```
sed 's_\\/_|_g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

for file `input`

```
$ cat input
bssapi_6 0\/0\/0\/9\/9
```

The following would do:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\\//,"|"); }1' input
```

Because we want to replace `\/` by `|`, here both `\` and `/` are escaped as `\\` and `\/` respectively. Therefore regex is `\\\/`.